# getting error in eclipse console saying fatal error

Tags: eclipse

I did some changes to my java classes in eclipse and got some errors and then I fixed those bugs.
Now I can not run my project and it keeps giving me following error and I do not know what to do with it . if any one had experience this error before please help me out

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3470), pid=4716, tid=8380
#  Error: ShouldNotReachHere()
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\project\hs_err_pid4716.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain it here .See here for reference

http://independentlyemployed.co.uk/2010/11/16/solved-internal-error-classfileparser-cpp3161/

http://independentlyemployed.co.uk/2010/11/17/worked-out-why/

Answer (score 0):

That's an error in the virtual machine, which does not necessarily indicate a problem with your own code. To me, the version number of your Java installation looks like a very old beta version of JDK 7. Please upgrade to a recent JDK 7 version, where that error might have long been fixed.